# Sound effects in Android Xamarin - C#

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

I wanted to add sound effects to my Android app. I am using `Xamarin` 4.2 and coding in C#. I searched for and found examples on how to do sound effects but could not find one in `C#` or the one I found had issues.

Could someone please show me how to do sound effects in C# in `xamarin` 4.2; something like playing a `.mp3` sound for one second without a media player pop up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the Xamarin docs](http://docs.xamarin.com/recipes/android/media/audio/play_audio/) it seems to be pretty straightforward:

> 1. Create a new Xamarin.Android application named PlayAudio.
> 2. Add a sub folder named raw under Resources.
> 3. Add a file named test.mp3 under raw.
> 4. In the Activity, create a class variable for the MediaPlayer.
>
>    `MediaPlayer _player;`
> 5. In the OnCreate method, call MediaPlayer.Create, passing the context and the resource identifier for the mp3.
>
>    `_player = MediaPlayer.Create(this, Resource.Raw.test);`
> 6. Call the Start method of the MediaPlayer.
>
>    `_player.Start();`

Comment: thank you; it is working in emulator; i do not know if there is going to be issue in device for IU thread issues